# mvn archetype:generate BUILD FAILURE

Tags: maven-2, maven-archetype

I am following the tutorial: http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/jersey-spring-and-jpa/
Here it says, run the command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://download.java.net/maven/2
```

After that give the groupId, ArtifactId, etc. I ran the above command. But before asking for groupId, it asked for:

Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains):

Since, this number is not given in the tutorial, I went through the given options in the command line and chose 3. After that it asked for the groupId and other. I gave all the options and then pressed enter. But I got a build failure saying Error reading POM.

Here's the output:

```
Choose archetype:
1: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-    
grizzly (Archetype for creating a RESTful web application with Jersey and Grizzly)
2: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 (Archetype for creating a RESTful web application with Jersey and Grizzly 2.x)
3: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp (Archetype for creating a Jersey based RESTful web application with WAR packaging)
4: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-ejb (Archetype for creating a Jersey based RESTful EJB application with WAR packaging)
5: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.faces:simple-jsf (Archetype for creating a simple JSF project)
6: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.faces.regression:i_jsf_XXXX-archetype (Archetype for mojarra JSF regression tests)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 3
Define value for property 'groupId': : com.persistent
Define value for property 'artifactId': : jerseySpringJPA
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : <CR>
Define value for property 'package':  com.persistent: : com.persistent.rest
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.persistent
artifactId: jerseySpringJPA
version: <CR>
package: com.persistent.rest
 Y: : Y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: jersey-quickstart-webapp:1.8
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.persistent
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.persistent.rest
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.persistent.rest
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: jerseySpringJPA
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /mwallet
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: <CR>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:32.278s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 02 00:55:41 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error reading POM -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have no idea why it is not reading the POM. Am I missing anything here? Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<CR>` means `Carriage Return` or in other words, press `Return/Enter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create a module without any problem.
Please see the attached screenshot.

It seems like the version number you passed is not correct.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you choose the "number" 3 as I did?

Comment: yes .. try to  run in debug mode and then see where it is failing ?

Comment: i was expecting that , it might be something related to version :)
but it doesn't make sense to me :( . Anyways now you can continue your tutorial. Thanks

Comment: NP , can you please mark it as answered and close it , so that it can save the time of others and they can focus on helping others. Thanks

Comment: I tried doing that. But it is saying I can mark my own answer only after two days. May be I am a new user, that's why. Can you please mark it for me and close it? Thanks!

Comment: actually you are the question owner so only you can do this . But if you want you can accept mine answer also for closing it :) - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue!

For

```
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
```

I was initially entering < CR > as mentioned in the tutorial. Now, I am leaving it blank, which is actually making the version as 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

This solved the issue. Now the build is successful! Here's the output:

```
5: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.faces:simple-jsf (Archetype for creating a simple JSF project)
6: http://download.java.net/maven/2 -> com.sun.faces.regression:i_jsf_XXXX-archetype (Archetype for mojarra JSF regression tests)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 3
Define value for property 'groupId': : com.persistent
Define value for property 'artifactId': : jerseySpringJPA     
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
Define value for property 'package':  com.persistent: : com.persistent.rest
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.persistent
artifactId: jerseySpringJPA
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com.persistent.rest
 Y: : Y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: jersey-quickstart-webapp:1.8
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.persistent
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.persistent.rest
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.persistent.rest
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: jerseySpringJPA
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /mwallet
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: /mwallet/jerseySpringJPA
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:04.013s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 02 01:49:42 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: <CR> is not a valid value for version. if you want to give you can give it like CR-1.0 .

Comment: `<CR>` means `Carriage Return` or in other words, press `Return/Enter`